# Possible to add SVG ::before element and have access to stroke and fill?

Tags: svg

Is it possible to add a before element in CSS like this:

```
    ul {
        li:before {
            content: url('../icons/fancy-symbol.svg');
        }
    }
```

and have access to the svg's objects (e.g. a specific line or rectangle) and properties (e.g. the stroke-width, strike and fill color)?

Or is there a workaround for these kind of situations?

The use case is to color some lines on hover and animate the svg on click.

Comment: The SVG's attributes and properties would not be externally modifiable in this situation.

Comment: Isn't that a huge flaw in the SVG implementation? Is access to the elements planned?

Comment: No it's a huge protection for your privacy. No access to the elements will ever be allowed because of that.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a fragment on the SVG URL, like `../icons/fancy-symbol.svg#red`, then have CSS inside the file react to that:

```
<style>
  #red:target ~ .some-element-here {
    fill: red;
  }
</style>
```

This won't let you specify properties dynamically, but it can be useful for interaction states, especially with a preprocessor.

Alternatively, if the SVG file is small enough, you can use preprocessors to change properties in a Data URI, like with [`sass-svg`](https://github.com/davidkpiano/sass-svg), or manually:

```
.li:before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
  fill='#{$color}'%3E...");
}
```

(By the way, it might be easier to use `ul { list-style-image: url(...) }` instead of pseudo-elements.)